# neural network and a intrusion detection system

Tags: neural-network

How do I approach the problem with a neural network and a intrusion detection system where by lets say we have an attack via FTP.

Lets say some one attempts to continuously try different logins via brute force attack on an ftp account.

How would I set the structure of the NN? What things do I have to consider? How would it recognise "similar approaches in the future"?

Any diagrams and input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is extremely general and a good answer is a project in itself.  I recommend contracting someone with experience in neural network design to help come up with an appropriate model or even tell you whether your problem is amenable to using a neural network.  A few ideas, though:

1. Inputs need to be quantized, so start by making a list of possible numeric inputs that you could measure.
2. Outputs also need to be quantized and you probably can't generate a simple "Yes/no" response.  Most likely you'll want to generate one or more numbers that represent a rough probability of it being an attack, perhaps broken down by category.
3. You'll need to accumulate a large set of training data that has been analyzed and quantized into the inputs and outputs you've designed.  Figuring out the process of doing this quantization is a huge part of the overall problem.
4. You'll also need a large set of validation data, which should be quantized in the same way as the training data, but that should not take any part in the training, as otherwise you will simply force a correlation network that may well be completely meaningless.
5. Once you've completed the above, you can think about how you want to structure your network and the specific algorithms you want to use to train it.  There is a wide range of literature on this topic, but, honestly, this is the simpler part of the problem.  Representing the problem in a way that can be processed coherently is much more difficult.